# rspec let method + loop

Tags: devise, rspec2, omniauth

i am having trouble running my rspec examples in a loop.

```
  describe "GET all providers" do
    let(:current_user) { Factory(:user) }

    [:twitter, :facebook, :google_oauth2].each do |provider|
      before :each do
        current_user.confirm!
        sign_in current_user

        request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
        request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.add_mock provider, {
          :uid => '123456789',
          :info => {
            :email => current_user.email
          }
        }
      end

      it 'should add the authorization' do            
        get provider # method to create the authorization
        authorization = Authorization.where(:provider => request.env["omniauth.auth"][:provider], :uid => request.env["omniauth.auth"][:uid]).first
        current_user.authorizations.should include authorization
      end
    end
  end
```

currently these examples all pass.  the problem though is that current_user is a new user instance through each iteration of the loop, despite memoizing the `current_user` method.  so if i add a test for `current_user.authorizations.count.should == 3` it fails.

this became less of needing to actually test it, and more understanding why it isnt behaving how i expect.  shouldn't `let(:current_user) { Factory(:user) }` persist the same user instance across all examples?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a gist I came up with that might help you understand `let` and `let!`:
https://gist.github.com/3489451

`let` memoizes the return value within each `it` example, but executes the block every time it is called for the first time in the example.

For example, if you call `current_user` the first time in an `it` example block, the `{ Factory(:user) }` block is executed. Calling `current_user` a second or any subsequent time within the same `it` example block does not execute the `{ Factory(:user) }` block; the return value is memoized.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. What was not clear for me before you say it was this sentence:   
`let` memoizes the return value within each `it` example, but executes the block every time it is called for the first time in the example.